# Magento patch 8788 with errors

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788v2

I needed to apply patch 8788 on a Magento 1.9.0.1. I did it in my test environment (previously mirrored from live environment) and I did it with no errors, applying first the 3941 and then the 8788.v2 for 1.9.0.1.

But when I did it in LIVE environment I got errors:

```
root:web$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-3941_EE_1.14.0.1_v1-2015-02-10-08-32-02.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

root:web$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v2-2016-10-14-09-37-14.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Backup.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
10 out of 10 hunks ignored
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file downloader/template/settings.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

In the app/etc/applied.patches.list file I find this:

```
2017-01-04 15:08:33 UTC | SUPEE-3941 | EE_1.14.0.1 | v1 | d35110621d80be22922611e2b0a502da054a95f0 | Tue Jul 15 11:57:57 2014 +0300 | v1.14.0.1..HEAD
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 489 (offset 3 lines).
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Backup.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 64 (offset 1 line).
```

My question is that now I don't know the "status" of the files ...

It's clear that 3941 was applied succefully, buy I don't understand the information of the patch output and the applied.patches.list file about the patch 8788.

Thank you!

P.D. Still thinking why I had no errors in test environment if it's an exact copy of live environment :-(

Comment: A patch will only apply when there are no errors detected. So the second Patch (8788) is not applied. Could you privide a list of succesfull applied patches from your pplied.patches.list?

Comment: All I have in applied.patches.list is in the body of the question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fully recommend to backup all main files (not necessary var and media dirs, since they can be huge), in order to restore files if the patch runs half way, as it happened to me.

The best thing is to do a simple script to get all the files "different" from your backup and restore them, and start again.

Standard patches are a crap ... if you don't have the luck to run them successfully, you will have a headache yes or yes.

I even run the patch in a test environment, and it worked, but then, in live, it failed ... so, prepare a backup yes or yes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Although the previous answer has already been accepted, I'd like to share my experiences with others.

You're recommended to rename the downloader directory so I'd make sure that you haven't done that before applying the patch, or make sure the directory has sufficient permissions.

I always apply my patches manually as I find more success - a great resource for this is;
https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788-without-ssh/

It's a simple drag/drop but be cautious if you've applied any core hacks to the affected files (always move them to local and log what you've adjusted, so you can update the local file with adjustments after the patch has been applied).

Hope this helps.